# How do I force Xorg to launch with display :0 in Redhat 7.2?

Tags: rhel, xorg, gdm

I have a Redhat 7.2 server that we realize sometimes loads with the DISPLAY variable set to something other than :0 (not sure why), which other apps have a dependency on. I'm not sure of the reason, but would like to try forcing Xorg to use :0, thinking it might be the easiest solution.  How can I control that?

To be clear, I'm looking to modify the Xorg that launches automatically via gdm.  I'm not sure A) where the appropriate script/configuration file to modify is, and B) what to add/change in that file.

Comment: try `startx -- :0`

Comment: @IporSircer Thanks, but I guess I should have been explicit that I'm looking to do it from gdm.  If I knew where to put that commandline in so gdm ran that, maybe it'd work for me.  I'll edit my question to be more specific.